# Generate images with transparent pixels instead of white in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I have a small piece of python code which generates 24x24 pixel avatars with random color schemes.Initially the code had only RGB colors in them, however, I want to have a transparent background so I added alpha value to all colors. Since I only want the background "bg" to be transparent, that is the only variable with alpha value 0.

The problem is that when i run the code, all saved images are blank. Below is the full code:

```
# Built with python 3, dependencies installed with pip 
# library to generate images - Pillow 
# https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html
from PIL import Image

# library to work with arrays 
# https://numpy.org/
import numpy as np

# library to interact with the operating system
import os

# library to generate random integer values
from random import seed
from random import randint

# gets path to be used in image creation mechanism, using os
dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)

# sets final image dimensions as 480x480 pixels
# the original 24x24 pixel image will be expanded to these 
dimensions
dimensions = 480, 480

# tells how many times to iterate through the following 
mechanism
# which equals the number of birds
# e.g. 
# for x in range(0-200) 
# would generate 201 birds numbered 0-200
for x in range(0, 50):

# using ETH block number as starting random number seed
b=11981207
seed(x+b)

#head color - randomly generate each number in an RGB color
hd = (randint(0, 256), randint(0, 256), randint(0, 256), 1)
c=randint(0,500)
seed(c)

#throat color - same as head color
th = (randint(0, 256), randint(0, 256), randint(0, 256), 1)
d = randint(0,1000)
seed(d)

#eye "white" color
# if random number between 1-1000 is 47 or less - Crazy Eyes!
if d > 47:
    # normal eyes are always the same color
    ew = (240,248,255,1)
    ey = (0, 0, 0, 1)
else:
    # crazy eyes have the same (154, 0, 0) pupil and a random 'eye white' color
    ew = (randint(0, 256), randint(0, 256), randint(0, 256), 1)
    ey = (154, 0, 0, 1)
e = randint(0,1000)
seed(e)

# beak color
f = randint(0, 1000)
if f > 500:
    # if random number is 501-1000 >> grey beak
    bk = (152, 152, 152, 1)
elif 500 >= f > 47:
    # 48-500 >> gold beak
    bk = (204, 172, 0, 1)
elif 47 >= f > 7:
    # 8 >> 47 >> red beak
    bk = (204, 0, 0, 1) 
else:
    # random number is 7 or less >> black beak
    bk = (0, 0, 0, 1) 

# background color
bg = (255, 255, 255, 0)
# outline color
ol = (0, 0, 0, 1)

basic_bird = [
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, ol, hd, hd, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, ew, ew, hd, ew, ew, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, ey, ew, hd, ey, ew, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, ol, ol, ol, ol, ol, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, bk, bk, bk, bk, bk, bk, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, bk, bk, bk, bk, bk, bk, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, bk, bk, bk, bk, bk, bk, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, th, ol, ol, ol, ol, ol, ol, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, th, th, th, th, th, ol, bg, bg, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, th, th, th, th, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, th, th, th, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, th, th, th, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, th, th, th, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, th, th, th, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg]
]

woodpecker = [
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, ol, hd, hd, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, ew, ew, hd, ew, ew, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, ey, ew, hd, ey, ew, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, ol, ol, ol, ol, ol, ol, ol, ol, ol, ol, ol, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, bk, bk, bk, bk, bk, bk, bk, bk, bk, ol, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, bk, bk, bk, bk, bk, bk, ol, ol, ol, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, th, ol, ol, ol, ol, ol, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, th, th, th, th, th, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, th, th, th, th, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, th, th, th, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, th, th, th, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, th, th, th, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, th, th, th, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg]
]

jay = [
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, ol, ol, ol, ol, ol, ol, ol, ol, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, ew, ew, hd, ew, ew, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, ey, ew, hd, ey, ew, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, ol, ol, ol, ol, ol, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, bk, bk, bk, bk, bk, bk, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, bk, bk, bk, bk, bk, bk, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, bk, bk, bk, bk, bk, bk, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, th, ol, ol, ol, ol, ol, ol, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, th, th, th, th, th, ol, bg, bg, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, th, th, th, th, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, th, th, th, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, th, th, th, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, th, th, th, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, th, th, th, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg]
]

eagle = [
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, ol, hd, hd, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, ew, ew, hd, ew, ew, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, ey, ew, hd, ey, ew, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, ol, ol, ol, ol, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, bk, bk, bk, bk, bk, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, bk, bk, bk, bk, bk, bk, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, bk, bk, bk, bk, bk, bk, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, ol, ol, ol, ol, ol, ol, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, ol, bg, bg, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, th, th, hd, hd, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, th, th, th, th, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, th, th, th, th, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg]
]

cockatoo = [
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, bg, bg, ol, ol, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, ol, bg, ol, ol, th, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, bg, ol, th, ol, bg, ol, th, th, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, ol, bg, ol, th, ol, ol, ol, th, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, th, ol, bg, ol, th, th, th, ol, th, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, th, th, ol, ol, ol, th, th, ol, th, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, ol, th, th, th, ol, th, th, th, th, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, ol, th, th, th, hd, hd, hd, th, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, ol, ol, ol, ol, th, th, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, th, th, th, hd, hd, ew, ew, hd, ew, ew, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, ol, ol, hd, hd, ey, ew, hd, ey, ew, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, th, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, ol, ol, ol, ol, ol, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, bk, bk, bk, bk, bk, bk, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, bk, bk, bk, bk, bk, bk, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, bk, bk, bk, bk, ol, ol, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, hd, hd, ol, ol, ol, ol, bg, bg, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, hd, hd, th, th, th, th, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, th, th, th, th, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, th, th, th, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, th, th, th, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, th, th, th, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg],
    [bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, ol, hd, th, th, th, ol, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg]
]

# choose which bird image to use
seed(f)
g = randint(0,1000)
if g > 250:
    # if random number is 251 - 1000 >> basic bird
    pixels = basic_bird
    p = "basic"
elif 250 >= g > 100:
    # 101 - 250 >> jay
    pixels = jay
    p = "jay"
elif 100 >= g > 40:
    # 41 - 100 >> woodpecker
    pixels = woodpecker
    p = "pecker"
elif 40 >= g > 5:
    # 6 - 40 >> eagle
    pixels = eagle
    p = "eagle"
else:
    # if random number is 5 or less >> cockatoo!!
    pixels = cockatoo
    p = "cockatoo"

# convert the pixels into an array using numpy
array = np.array(pixels, dtype=np.uint8)

# use PIL to create an image from the new array of pixels
new_image = Image.fromarray(array)
new_image = new_image.resize(dimensions, resample=0)
imgname = dirname + '/bird_images/' + (str(x)) + '.png'
new_image.save(imgname)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. For debugging help, you need to provide a [mre] including complete code and the full error message. To start, you haven't even mentioned which image library you're using. You can [edit]. See [ask] if you want more tips.

Comment: Have you looked online for a tutorial? [Example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-transparent-png-image-with-python-pillow/)

Comment: `pixels` is not defined. Maybe you meant `basic_bird`? Also undefined are `hd, ey, ew, bk, th`. Please make sure you've provided a [mre]. We should be able to copy-paste your code and run it.

Comment: If you use a 4-component (RGBA) color for any one element of your array, you have to use 4-component colors for *everything*.  Add an alpha of 255 to all the other colors.